# I am looking for a 80's scifi movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie was created in the 80's I think; it was a live action sci-fi movie for kids. I just remember the last scene. The evil and the hero (man) and robots are in a spaceship and someone using an electric whip and cut the enemy into parts...

The last scene was in the spaceship and the planet Earth was seen in the back window if the spaceship... Someone used a special whip, that looked like a lighting cord, and cut someone into parts.

I just remember that was in a dark scene, and the whip looked like a lightsaber, but it did not look like a lightsaber from *Star Wars* because it was moving like a cord that could cut everything.

Comment: Johny Mnemonic has a scene like that. But no spaceship. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeO_vuhMM9o  There is also a scene in robocop 3 with ninja robots. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F282ZaQXMOc

Comment: in the jonny mnemonic scane the whipping just like I have remember, but I am looking for a scigj movie for kids and the final scene was in a spaceship

Comment: Or like that one https://onthefringescinema.wordpress.com/2016/01/08/new-year-on-the-fringes-fringe-cinema-crossing-the-streams/masters-of-the-universe-he-man-laser-whip/ (masters of the universe)

Comment: no it was not what I am looking for because the whipping was cutted fomeone to parts

Comment: Guessing probably not *Captain EO* either, since that's more about the dancing than the whipping.

Comment: Nothing promising in https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LightningLash

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RazorFloss might be a bit more handy.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The [Whip Sword](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhipSword) page has "In Metal Heroes, Space Sheriff Shaider used a laser sword that he could transform into a laser whip at will."  Right time frame, but a TV show.

Comment: Could you see the hero's face, or was he wearing a helmet?

Comment: Was there a talking dog?

Answer (score 3):

After some thought, this could be *Tron* from 1982.

The movie is about a games programmer that gets digitized by a malevolent AI and ends up inside a mainframe computer, where the programs walk around and talk just like normal people.

- the background "sky" inside the mainframe is always dark, apart from structures in the skyline.
- the clothing worn by the programs is stylized a lot like circuit boards, which might give the impression of robots
- the programs have the ability to fight each other using identity discs that act like laser-edged trick frisbees.  While not a whip, the neon afterglow and the way they move might suggest a whip.
- the "hero" attacking the "evil" could be the program Tron trying to attack the MCP, the AI that controls the mainframe, there's not only a lot of guards but the MCP conjures barriers that Tron is constantly trying to break through
- Flynn, the programmer that's trying to get back to the real world, is on a spaceship-looking transport at the time of this fight and jumps down into the "beam" of the MCP to distract and give Tron the opening he needs.
- Sark, the MCPs head lackey, gets his head split open by Tron's disc, and his insides look a lot like a robot.

Things that don't match are the "Earth" in the background of a window, but there's enough fuzziness in this match that it might just be an honest mistake.

Here's a visual (from IMDB) of Tron against the "sky" if that helps:

[image]

Comment: no it was not the tron